# Why does the Kernel shut down?

Tags: time-series, crash

I didn't see this coming:

```
ClearAll[randomTimeSeries]

randomTimeSeries[seed_ : RandomInteger[{10^6, 10^7}], m_ : 3, n_ : 30,iRandRng_ : {1, 7}] :=     
    Module[{ds, vs, junk, ts},
      {junk, {ts}} = Do[
        BlockRandom[
          ds = NestList[(DatePlus[#, -RandomInteger[iRandRng]] &), AbsoluteTime[], n - 1] // Reverse;
          vs = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n] // Accumulate;
          TimeSeries[vs, {ds}, ResamplingMethod -> {"Interpolation", 0}, MetaInformation -> {"seed" -> seed + j}] // Quiet /* Sow, 
            RandomSeeding -> seed + j], {j, 1, m}] // Reap;
      ts // (TimeSeriesThread[Mean, #] &)
 ]
```

Every single time I evaluate `randomTimeSeries[RandomInteger[{10^6, 10^7}]] // Accumulate` I get

1. Error messages about interpolation even though I am using `Quiet`
2. High memory and CPU usage and
3. The Kernel quits with messages about there being insufficient memory

I'm on Win10, using v.12.1.

Does anybody know whats going on ?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: If you remove the Accumulate, you get the warnings (they're not errors, they are warning you that its extrapolating, not interpolating) and a time series object. Maybe look carefully at the time series object to see why it is causing problems...

Comment: @bills shouldn't there be no messages since I'm using `Quiet`? It really threw my schedule out the window today but I think the problem is due to the fact that there are non-regular series involved; using `TemporalRegularity->True` seems to make the Kernel happy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is as designed. If we set

```
ts = randomTimeSeries[RandomInteger[{10^6, 10^7}]]
```

then `RegularlySampledQ[ts]` is `False` which means that calling `Accumulate` on it will first trigger `TimeSeriesResample` on `ts` with respect to the minimal time step:

```
In[3]:= ts["MinimumTimeIncrement"]

Out[3]= {0.00926208}
```

which is very small compared to the other time increments:

```
In[5]:= Differences[ts["Times"]] // MinMax

Out[5]= {0.00926208, 432000.}
```

and hence the huge memory usage and hang and/or crash.

If the objective is to accumulate values only then either call `Accumulate` on `ts["Values"]` or create new `TimeSeries` object that forces `TemporalRegularity` to `True` and then apply `Accumulate`:

```
In[6]:= ts1 = TimeSeries[ts, TemporalRegularity -> True];

In[9]:= (Accumulate[ts1] // Head) // AbsoluteTiming

Out[9]= {0.000467, TemporalData}
```